# Magento 1.9 to 2 migration

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I have done magento 1.9 to 2 migration(data, settings) using [this link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html) and [this link](https://github.com/ubertheme/magento2_data_migration/releases).

Is it possible to migrate code from 1.9 to 2.

Comment: if any of the answers provided helped to solve your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can't migrate code from Magento 1 to Magento 2.
**All extension is created in magento1 are not compatible to Magento 2**. You have to create from scratch or support to third-party extension provider company for the magento2 extension.

You also not migrate from theme code. **You have to create the new theme for Magento 2 because theme structure for Magento 1 is totally different from magento1**.

You can only migrate **orders, customers, url-rewrite, products, category and configuration settings`** from Magento 1.

You have to write code again for magento 2.

Thanks.

Comment: I am looking for a way to bring in custom tables from Magento 1 to Magento 2 DB. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Themes and extensions have to be rewritten.

There are tools that help developers converting their code but a fully automated solution is not possible.

- Official "code migration" tool: https://github.com/magento/code-migration
- M1M2 Converter by Unirgy: https://github.com/unirgy/convertm1m2

For code that's not too complex and does not depend on too many implementation details (i.e. rewrites), you might get usable results, otherwise it's at least a good starting point for configuration files and standard boilerplate code.

Also, to adhere to Magento 2 best practices you will need to change most of the converted code because it's a 1:1 mapping of models and collections and those should not be used in Magento 2 if you can do the same using the service contracts.

A general advise: Try to make as much as possible of your business logic independent from Magento, this way your critical code does not need any changes to be used in Magento 2. I wrote a series of blog articles about how to achieve this:

- https://www.integer-net.com/magento-1-magento-2-shared-code-extensions/

And also recently gave a presentation how to refactor existing extensions to decouple them from Magento:

- https://speakerdeck.com/schmengler/porting-a-complex-extension-to-magento-2